# Remove Add and Delete buttons from DataObject ModelAdmin

Tags: silverstripe

I have custom data object with predefined entries. I don't want user to delete or add any new entries from GridField's edit form. Is there a way to remove those two buttons form ModelAdmins GridField edit form?

Using: Silverstripe 3.6

Comment: Do you want to remove them globally, or just from single records? Also: what version of SilverStripe?

Comment: Both, single record edit and, list view. Silverstripe 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i got it my self. If you want to remove Add and Delete buttons from managed model's ModelAdmin you need to add this code

```
class Translation extends DataObject {

    // ...
    public function canDelete($member = null) {
        return false;
    }
}

class TranslationAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    public static $managed_models = ['Translation'];
    static $url_segment = 'translations';
    static $menu_title = 'Translations';

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null) {
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

        $form
          ->Fields()
          ->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass))
          ->getConfig()
          ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldDeleteAction')
          ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps for someone in future.

Comment: This is fine, as long as you just manage one model in the GridField. Also it won't prevent delete or creating new items if you have a module like `betterbuttons` installed.

Answer (score 3):

To remove actions from a `GridField` "globally", eg. for all records managed by the GridField, it's best to modify the `GridFieldConfig` instance.

In a ModelAdmin context, this is possible by overriding `getEditForm`:

```
public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
{
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
    // make sure to check if the modelClass matches the object you want to edit
    // otherwise, the config will get applied to all models managed  
    // by this ModelAdmin instance
    if ($this->modelClass === Translation::class) {
        $fieldName = $this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass);
        /** @var GridField $grid */
        if ($grid = $form->Fields()->dataFieldByName($fieldName)) {
            $grid->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType([
                GridFieldDeleteAction::class,
                GridFieldAddNewButton::class
            ]);
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

However, the user might still be able to delete a record in the detail-view. But since both, GridField and detail-view respect DataObject permissions, you should make use of them… this also prevents that a user can delete the object via other means.

A simplistic solution would be (these methods should be implemented in your DataObject):

```
public function canDelete($member = null)
{
    return Permission::check('ADMIN');
}

public function canCreate($member = null)
{
    return Permission::check('ADMIN');
}

public function canView($member = null)
{
    return true;
}

public function canEdit($member = null)
{
    return Permission::check('CMS_ACCESS_TranslationAdmin');
}
```

That way, only administrators can create/delete these objects. They can be viewed by all users and edited by users that have access to your ModelAdmin section (here named "TranslationAdmin").